# Thoughts on organizing code for multiple mysql queries in php scripts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, code-formatting

This is a random question I think and it has more to do with style and organization.
I have a web application where I connect with a MySQL database using PDO and in some scripts there are a lot of queries one after the other which don't necessarily concern the same tables. i.e I will execute a SELECT statement in one, and then depending on some values I will UPDATE another and finally go and DELETE from another one.

The thing is I only recently learned PHP and MySQL and because I wasn't sure and wanted to be careful and to find easily any problems (and a little because I am a little ocd and anal about silly things like uniformity and coding style) in every query I used the following format

```
try {
    $statement = "
        UPDATE/SELECT   ...
        FROM/SET    ...
        WHERE   ...";
    $query = $dbcnx->prepare($statement);
    $flag = $query->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $errorMsg = "...";
    error_log($errorMsg,3,'../../xxx.log');
    $response = ...;
    $dbcnx->null;
    return $response;
}
$result = $query->fetch/fetchAll/fetcColumn...
```

so I could find where any problem would occur (try/catch) and to be safe against injections and invalid characters (prepare) (I had some personal checks but I am pretty sure that a function specifically made for would be better).

When I had one or two queries it was fine but after the code grew it became a little too much code for little action/substance (like 16 lines for one query...)

So I would like some advise. 
How do I make my code more manageable?
Is there some fundamental error in my logic on structure (the way I wrote it)?
Is there some rule for using try/catch? Is it more for developing and debugging and afterwards you can remove some blocks of it?

I was thinking of making a function of just this block of code and calling it with the statement as a parameter. So I would just 'type' the query in the main body and then call the function where it would be prepared, executed and then return the result. Of course then I would always use fetchAll and would return an associative array but I think as long the datasets are small the memory usage would be fine (in any case in nowadays systems it should take A LOT to notice a difference, I think)...

Any thoughts are welcome.

I realize this is not actually a problem with code and settings and s/w and programs like other questions in here but I do hope it still follows the spirit.

Comment: Your question might be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question is not for codereview. There is nothing to review. The code is a sketch to show the practice the OP is using at the moment. It is perfect question for Stackoverflow. Way better than 99% of "find me a typo" questions. **Why everyone is so eager to drive away good programming questions from Stackoverflow?** Please don't closevote if your only reason is you just have no idea what to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, thanks for the excellent question.
To my huge surprise, there are extremely few questions here asking for better code practices.
Nobody cares for their code quality, but everyone asks for the code to copy/paste and never mind what they've got.

Next, there are 2 great things you need to know:

1. Try..catch is an exceptional (pun not intended) operator. It have to be used very seldom, for the errors you can recover from, following the code to handle. Using it to just log errors is a deadly sin and a waste of a precious and powerful mechanism.
2. What you really need is a **database abstraction layer** to do all the dirty job and handle complex cases.

You need to read on Exceptions.
That's greatest improvement in the programming languages since syntax highlighting.
They are not intended to be catched immediately. The point is quite contrary - to catch exceptions in a centralized way, having single exception handler.

But even without a handler Exeptions are good enough. An erroneous query will halt your script, will show a 503 error and will either log an error message or show it on-screen according to PHP settings - nothing to want more!

So, just get rid of all that handling code and just tell PHP which file to use to log errors

```
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('error_log','/path/to/log');
```

and you will get the same result with dramatically less code.

As for the abstraction library, just look at your code:

```
$statement = "UPDATE/SELECT  FROM/SET    ...         WHERE   ...";
$query = $dbcnx->prepare($statement);
$flag = $query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch/fetchAll/fetcColumn...
```

**four** lines, only **one** of which is meaningful.

Why not to make it one line already -

```
$result = $db->getRes( $statement); //okay, leaving query separate for readability
```

just to give you idea on how it could be - my own [database abstraction class](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)
it is based on top of mysqli, but can be rewritten easily on whatever else driver including PDO

Comment: Thanks. I knew that my try/catch use was wasteful... It was obvious in a something sort of feels off.. I will check your code and hopefully I will understand

Comment: Ok... I think I got it... I will have to read a little more on the class but I think I got it. I was a little confused because I was thinking of instance of classes in more classic programs where they are available all the time after their creation. Here in every new call of the script you create an instance all over again and do what you will do with it and with it's end it is destroyed.? I have a lot of work in ahead of me... I was almost done with my little website... Oh well, live and learn